# squid3 TCP_MISS even even saying "Serving from cache"

Tags: squid

I would like to setup a proxy to cache microsoft sharepoint online. However, even getting some progresses, I still could not understand why it is still TCP_MISS.

OS: Centos 7

Squid: initially 3.3.8 (centos default) and upgraded to 3.5.22 later

ssl_bump is utilised for https interception

refresh pattern:
refresh_pattern -i .(xz|rpm) 14400 50% 18000 override-expire override-lastmod ignore-reload ignore-no-cache ignore-private ignore-auth

the test file for downloading is kernel-plus-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.centos.plus.x86_64.rpm which was uploaded to sharepoint.

with "debug_options 22,70,9", I am getting messages in cache.log as follows:

> 2016/12/08 16:36:10.383 kid1| ctx: exit level  0
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:10.384 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(291) refreshCheck: checking freshness of 'https ://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/its/itst/int/kernel-plus-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.centos.plus.x86_64.rpm'
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:10.384 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(312) refreshCheck: Matched '.(xz|rpm) 864000 50%% 1080000'
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:10.384 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(314) refreshCheck:       age:    2225
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:10.384 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(316) refreshCheck:       check_time:     Thu, 08 Dec 2016 21:36:10 GMT
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:10.384 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(318) refreshCheck:       entry->timestamp:       Thu, 08 Dec 2016 20:59:05 GMT
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:10.384 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(173) refreshStaleness: STALE: expires 1481230745 < check_time 1481232970
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:10.384 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(338) refreshCheck: Staleness = 2225
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:10.384 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(362) refreshCheck: YES: Must revalidate stale object (origin set no-cache or private)
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:10.384 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(654) getMaxAge: getMaxAge: 'https ://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/its/itst/int/kernel-plus-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.centos.plus.x86_64.rpm'
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:12.247 kid1| ctx: enter level  0: 'https ://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/its/itst/int/kernel-plus-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.centos.plus.x86_64.rpm'
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:12.247 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(291) refreshCheck: checking freshness of 'https ://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/its/itst/int/kernel-plus-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.centos.plus.x86_64.rpm'
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:12.247 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(312) refreshCheck: Matched '.(xz|rpm) 864000 50%% 1080000'
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:12.247 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(314) refreshCheck:       age:    63
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:12.247 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(316) refreshCheck:       check_time:     Thu, 08 Dec 2016 21:37:12 GMT
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:12.247 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(318) refreshCheck:       entry->timestamp:       Thu, 08 Dec 2016 21:36:09 GMT
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:12.247 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(173) refreshStaleness: STALE: expires 1481232969 < check_time 1481233032
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:12.247 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(338) refreshCheck: Staleness = 63
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:12.247 kid1| 22,3| refresh.cc(497) refreshCheck: NO: Serving from cache - even though explicit expiry has passed, we enforce Min value (override-expire option)
>
> 2016/12/08 16:36:12.247 kid1| 22,3| http.cc(482) cacheableReply: YES because HTTP status 200

and TCP_MISS in access.log.

my questions are:
1. why did squid refreshcheck twice on one downloading request?
2. I guess that the squid decides to "Serving from cache" in the second refreshcheck, why still TCP_MISS in access.log?

if offline_mode is on, the cache has served the download happily with TCP_OFFLINE_HIT.

Please advise how could I fix the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone has suggestion on this?

Comment: no one could shed the light on me? this is my first question on stackoverflow, please let me know if any more information is need. I have tried to fix the issue by myself for few days now and really could not make it work. any hints or clues would be appreciated. thanks!